# mwclient - browsebysubject - SMW

Tags: python, mediawiki-api, semantic-mediawiki, mwclient

I have been toying around with [mwclient](https://github.com/mwclient/mwclient) to query a wiki installations running the SMW extension.

It is quite convenient to have the "ask" method available to the mwclient.client.Site.
However I want to take my queries further and use the
browsebysubject API module to get all the property::value pairs of a particular page. Just like in the example:
http://www.beachapedia.org/api.php?action=browsebysubject&subject=Bogue_Banks&format=json
in which the page Bogue_Banks is "browsed", with the API returning page properties and values.

Now mwclient does not have a **browsebysubject** method. 
Given that fact what would be the way to go about doing that query with mwclient? With the [raw_api](http://mwclient.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/site.html#mwclient.client.Site.raw_api) method?

If you could provide an example it would be great

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

The [generic API method](http://mwclient.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/site.html#mwclient.client.Site.api) is the way to go:

`site.api('browsebysubject', subject='Bogue_Banks')`